# Change element when other element is hovered in CSS

Tags: html, css

I'm quite confused, as I always thought that you could change an html element's css when another element is hovered directly in css:

```
h1:hover h2 {
color:red;
}
```

I recall with all I learned that the above code should change h2's color to red when h1 is hovered over, but it doesn't work. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: [check](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4502633/how-to-affect-other-elements-when-a-div-is-hovered)

Comment: That will only work if `h2` is a a child or grandchild node of `h1`

Comment: You can do it with `JQuery`

Answer (score 0):

Only if h2 is nested into h1 in your markup. But nesting heading is forbidden by html w3c specs.

Answer (score 0):

You are using a descendant combinator, so your rule:

> Selects any h2 element that is a descendant of a h1 element which is in a hover state.

[source](http://tux.theopalgroup.com/cgi-bin/css3explainer/selectoracle.py)

It isn't possible to have an h2 that is a descendant of an h1 in HTML (it wouldn't make sense: How could a sub-heading be part of a heading?).

The [combinators](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#combinators) section of the specification might show you something that allows you to trace a path through your DOM (which we can't see because you didn't include your HTML) from your H1 to your H2.